# jodd build simple auth issues

Tags: jodd

I was trying to build a simple auth mechanism using madvoc and interceptors but it seems that the tutorial at

http://jodd.org/doc/example/auth-with-interceptors.html

is a little bit outdated.
I think that the  tag was removed and I was not able to find the substituent.
How should we use the form in general and what is the recommended auth mechanism?

P.S. - I`m using latest jodd version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest answer is to check module `jodd-joy`. Look at the package `jodd.joy.auth`. It contains latest `AuthTag`, `AuthAction` that may be used, etc. This module contains some helpers for build an web-app even faster.

I will update this answer later, with more info - actually, I will try to update the website, too. But in general, the idea behind the auth is not much changed;)